# Data structure or design pattern for property that crosses two classes

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, data-structures

I'm working on a calculator for balancing investments to match a model portfolio.

The classes that I developed look like this:

```
export class Portfolio {
    public name: string;
    public risks: Risk[];
}

export class Risk  {
    name: string;
    funds: Fund[];
}

export class Fund {
    shares: number;
    value?: number;
    percent: number;
}
```

This structure works, but the `Fund[]` is really a property of the portfolio and the property on `Fund` called percent is the only thing that changes between the Risks. In the application the user can toggle between risks and see what they need to buy and sell, but when they do, all of the inputs clear because they are bound to a different instance.

If `funds` is moved from Risk to Portfolio how can the risk class store a value for each fund?

```
export class Portfolio {
    name: string;
    risks: Risk[];
    funds: Fund[];
}

export class Risk  {
    constructor (public name: string, public percents: number[]) {}
}

export class Fund {
    shares: number;
    value?: number;
    percent: number;
}

export class PortfoliosService {
    setPercents(riskName) {
        this.currentRisk = this.currentPortfolio.risks.filter(x => x.name === riskName)[0];
        for (const i in this.currentRisk.percents) {
            this.currentPortfolio.funds[i].percent = this.currentRisk.percents[i];
        }
    }
}
```

This works as well, the problem is that it relies on two independent arrays being the same size and in the same order. Is there any way to associate the percent value with an instance of fund so that if they don't match it is caught by the compiler?

Comment: Can you give each fund a unique and each risk another unique id? Then you could just use the IDs instead of depending on the arrays to be the same length.

Comment: @ChrisSharp can you provide an answer? I get the idea of what you're saying but I'm new to typescript and don't know a good way of grouping the arrays by id

Comment: @ChrisSharp I also don't think there is a way to guarantee at compile time that every risk has a value for every fund with that approach

Comment: You can initialize them with a value or run a loop if you know the correct values at runtime.

Comment: If this answer has promise but you still need more about how to access the properties or something just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could create each array as an array of objects and give each object a unique id. The unique id could then be used to locate the objects so you wouldn't need to be concerned about whether or not the length of the arrays was the same.

```
export class PortfoliosService {
    currentPortfolio: Portfolio;

    createRisks(id, name, percents) {
        const obj = {
            id: id,
            name: name,
            percents: percents
        };
        this.currentPortfolio.risks.push(obj);
    }

    createFund(id, shares, value, percent) {
        const obj = {
            id: id,
            shares: shares,
            value: value,
            percent: percent
        };
        this.currentPortfolio.funds.push(obj);
    }
    // other logic that uses ids instead of array lengths to access array members
}
```